# Creating an Icon with a Tranparent Background

Tags: java, background, icons, png, transparency

I'm using ImageIcons that I downloaded from a free icon site in my JButtons. Two of them have white backgrounds, and the other one has a black background. I would prefer not to have a background color clash, so I want to make all the backgrounds transparent. I've seen ways to make image backgrounds transparent, but I thought it was kinda roundabout to turn my ImageIcons into Images and back again. Is there a way to make the backgrounds of ImageIcons transparent without converting to Images?

Comment: what is the format and the background of the actual images that you're using?

Comment: The format is png. Some of the backgrounds are white, some are black.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Java-solution, but it's a solution I use frequently nonetheless. Download/install [Paint.NET](http://download.cnet.com/Paint-NET/3000-2192_4-10338146.html) and follow [this](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/12196-making-backgrounds-of-images-transparent/) discussion on how to make the background of images transparent. And then use the resulting image for the `ImageIcon`.

Answer (score 0):

Another non java solution: with photoshop you can select a small white rectangle of the background part, and then menu "Select" > "Similar" if you want to delete all white pixels, or "Grow" if you want to delete all white pixels touching your existing selection.